# JUnit Could not find class: package_name.class

Tags: java, junit

I just dropped the JUnit folder into /System/Library/Java/Extensions/. I'm able to get JUnit to run, but it can't find my test class.

I'm running this command (plus a few variants) from the containing folder of the package (/containing_folder/package_name/):

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore package_name.ClassTest
```

but it tells me:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: package_name.ClassTest
```

My system info:
MacOS 10.7.2 • Java 1.6.0_26 • JUnit 4.10

Addendum:
I've moved JUnit per suggestion and tried running JUnit on my test class with the following bash script, but I'm still getting the same error message.

```
#!/bin/bash
export CLASSPATH=/Users/myname/Desktop/Programming/Java/junit4.10/junit-4.10.jar:/Users/myname/Desktop/Programming/Java/:/Users/myname/Desktop/Programming/Java/package_name.jar
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore package_name.ClassTest
```

Any *nix or mac users see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

P.S. No, "myname", "ClassTest", and "package_name" are not the real names used on my system - they've been anonymized.

Comment: How are you setting the classpath? I assume when you type `package_name` it's just a placeholder for your real package name?

Comment: Don't drop anything in the extensions folder, unless you're **very** sure that it's the right thing to do. It's **usually** the **wrong** way to make classes available. *Very* few things actually need to (and should) go there.

Answer (score 0):

Goood Morning,

the trick is (like Dave Newton already said) to set the Classpath right. In a batch file it would look like this:

```
set CLASSPATH=D:\_zip\lib\junit.jar;D:\containing_folder
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore package_name.ClassTest
```

The important thing here is to have the following things in your Classpath:

- JUnit class files
- Your class files, including your JUnit test classes
- Libraries your class files depend on

This means you have to set the **containing folder of your class files** (in my example it's **D:\_zip**) in the classpath. So you can set the full classname (including packages) as an argument for the JUnitCore.

**A good FAQ is here: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_1**

---

***Update:*** I'm not sure how the bash script und MacOS works, but if you have your classes packed in a JAR file, it would be enough, to set the CLASSPATH inside the JAR files' manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_26-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: Gruber ^^
Implementation-Vendor: Company
Implementation-Title: Title
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: package_name.ClassTest
Class-Path: /Users/myname/Desktop/Programming/Java/junit4.10/junit-4.10.jar
```

The *Main-Class* is not really important for the JUnit tests, but i left it here. The manifest file is set inside the JAR:

```
package_name.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

You can set it manually or Eclipse will set it for you (export to jar, etc), if you use it ^^.

With this Manifest set, the script should look like this (called from the same directory as the jar file):

```
set CLASSPATH=package_name.jar
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore package_name.ClassTest
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wrote a bash script to do something like this (with different syntax due to being on a Mac), but I wasn't able to get anywhere. Any ideas?

I edited my question to add script info.

Comment: I added a working manifest file entry for the JAR file. This works for me on my Win7 System. I'm not sure about the bash script, but is it correct, that the entries are separated by a colon? ... Anyway, tell me if this worked ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-cp` option.

`java -cp class_path_or_jar_separated_by_comma class_to_run`